# What is mnt_cache in slabtop output on Linux?

Tags: linux, kernel, memory

```
OBJS ACTIVE  USE OBJ SIZE  SLABS OBJ/SLAB CACHE SIZE NAME
5520396 3165734  57%    0.38K 131438       42   2103008K mnt_cache
```

I searched the kernel source code, only 1 hit, and I'm unable to interpret from it. https://github.com/torvalds/linux/search?q=mnt_cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [the slab cache](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/core-api/memory-allocation.html) for [`struct mount`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.1.8/source/fs/mount.h#L39) allocations which are used to store information about mount points. The cache is [initialised in `mnt_init`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.1.8/source/fs/namespace.c#L4410) and used whenever a `struct mount` needs to be instantiated [in `alloc_vfsmnt`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.1.8/source/fs/namespace.c#L196).

Comment: Thank you. Worth noting for whoever comes to this via Google, in my case, the real culprit was NOT `mnt_cache` and `slabtop` was was misleading. With `slabinfo -a` output, I was able to identify that the slab shown as `mnt_cache`  was also used by other structs like `blkdev_requests dm_old_clone_request mnt_cache ip_vs_conn`. In my case, the culprit was `ip_vs_conn`.

I've no idea why `slabtop` decides to choose one alias randomly which has the shortest length. https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/654058e67b9490a655d9a01e838168fb499f2aa3/tools/vm/slabinfo.c#L349